# Нарисовать фигуру с помощью Path JavaFx

Tags: javafx

не совсем понимаю как сделать Path в виде "сообщения чата".
Нужно, что бы было так
[image: Изображение которое должно получится]

Пробовал, но не как не могу уйти от элипса

```
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.scene.Group;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
 import javafx.scene.shape.ArcTo;
 import javafx.scene.shape.ClosePath;
 import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
 import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;

 public class Main extends Application {
     @Override
     public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
         Group root = new Group();

         Path path = new Path();

         ArcTo arcTo = new ArcTo();
         arcTo.setX(151);
         arcTo.setY(100);
         arcTo.setSweepFlag(false);
         arcTo.setLargeArcFlag(true);
         arcTo.setRadiusX(40);
         arcTo.setRadiusY(100);
         arcTo.setXAxisRotation(90);

         path.getElements().addAll(new MoveTo(150, 100), arcTo, new ClosePath());
         path.setStroke(Color.web("#4682B4"));

         root.getChildren().add(path);

         primaryStage.setResizable(false);
         primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 460));
         primaryStage.show();
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
     }
 }
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Может вам разбить блок на три вертикальные секции, изгибы нарисовать в пейнте, и сделать их фоном?

Comment: А вам именно Path надо или просто надо этот bubble?

Comment: Да нужен именно Path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну держите тогда через Path, но с моей точки зрения через SVG все немного элегантнее и более гибко:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        //Creating a Path
        Path path = new Path();
        Integer startX = 100;
        Integer startY = 100;
        Integer width = 200;
        Integer height = 80;
        Integer radius = 10;
        Integer triangle = 10;

        MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(startX+radius, startY);
        LineTo line1 = new LineTo(startX+width-radius, startY);
        ArcTo arc1 = new ArcTo(radius, radius, 0, startX+width, startY+radius, false, true);
        LineTo line2 = new LineTo(startX+width, startY+height-triangle);
        LineTo line21 = new LineTo(startX+width+triangle, startY+height);
        LineTo line3 = new LineTo(startX+radius, startY+height);
        ArcTo arc3 = new ArcTo(radius, radius, 0, startX, startY+height-radius, false, true);
        LineTo line4 = new LineTo(startX, startY+radius);
        ArcTo arc4 = new ArcTo(radius, radius, 0, startX+radius, startY, false, true);
        path.getElements().add(moveTo);
        path.getElements().addAll(line1, arc1, line2, line21, line3, arc3, line4, arc4);
        path.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        Group root = new Group(path);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 300);
        stage.setTitle("Bubble");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Ну и стартовыми значениями можете задавать координаты и размеры.

Comment: Спасибо! Как раз то что нужно.
На счет SVG может вы и правы, буду признателен, если добавите ссылочку на какой-нибудь хороший пример.

Comment: @hmeli7 https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7f/Speech_bubble.svg - вот это пример именно svg, там же можно почитать что такое SVG. Просто SVG - это векторная графика.